# How to check if an object is a subclass of Handle

Tags: matlab

What is the way to check if an object is a subclass of the [handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html)?

I tried a few searches ([example](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+check+if+an+object+is+subclass+of+handler+class&oq=matlab+check+if+an+object+is+subclass+of+handle+class)) but can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html), like this

```
isa(h,'handle')
```